# Using Multiple Timers in C#

Tags: c#, timer

I would like to use multiple timers in my code to process api calls on different intervals. I have found varying opinions on multiple timers. While I could use one timer with a finer interval, for cleanliness I would much prefer multiple timers.

The timers are used to regularly used to make an api call and check the market rate on an exchange / manage orders.

I am concerned about two things. 1. Timer interrupt occurring during the Eventhandler of another timer 2. Timer interrupt occurring before the Eventhandler code has completed running.

If I use Timer2.Stop() during Timer1 EventHandler does that pause the timer or reset it?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 Timer2.Stop(); //
 Timer1.Stop(); //

 /// Process Timer1 Functions


 Timer2.Start(); // Does this reset the count?
 Timer1.Start(); // 
}
```

Comment: I believe there are 3 .NET classes named Timer (in WinForms, in System.Timers and in System.Threading). What are you trying to do? What kind of Timer(s) are you using? What does you setup code look like?

Comment: what do you mean by _Does this reset the count?_? reset count of what?

Answer (score 1):

Don't refer to a second timer from within a single timer's tick event. Let each timer function independently:

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Perform first API call
}

private void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Perform second API call
}
```

Don't bother trying to stop and start the timer either. Unless these timers need to do things in a highly synchronized manner or with very tight time tolerances.

Comment: So what happens if timer2 occurs while Timer1 is running?

Comment: It's no big deal. The timers function independently of one another.